# Why can't get Google Map V2 in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am implementing Google Map V2 in My Android application. I Have done all the steps in these two links :
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
so please don't send them as answers.I have downloaded the Maps API, copied it into Eclipse Workspace, marked it as library, referenced it in my project. But no success. I'm still getting the errors :, Can someone help me please.Thanks to apreciate.

Here is Log Cat information:

```
01-13 11:41:09.106: I/dalvikvm(403): Could not find method info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.getFragmentManager, referenced from method info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.initilizeMap
01-13 11:41:09.106: W/dalvikvm(403): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 27599: Linfo/androidhive/googlemapsv2/MainActivity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
01-13 11:41:09.106: D/dalvikvm(403): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
01-13 11:41:09.106: D/dalvikvm(403): VFY: dead code 0x0007-0028 in Linfo/androidhive/googlemapsv2/MainActivity;.initilizeMap ()V
01-13 11:41:09.772: W/dalvikvm(403): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment; (26)
01-13 11:41:09.772: W/dalvikvm(403): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment;' failed
01-13 11:41:09.796: D/AndroidRuntime(403): Shutting down VM
01-13 11:41:09.796: W/dalvikvm(403): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  ... 11 more
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  ... 20 more
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2-1.apk]
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
01-13 11:41:10.191: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  ... 23 more
01-13 11:46:10.624: I/Process(403): Sending signal. PID: 403 SIG: 9
```

Here is Activity code.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            /*Could not find method info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.getFragmentManager, 
              referenced from method info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.initilizeMap*/

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

            // Showing / hiding your current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming controls
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            // Enable / Disable my location button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            double latitude = 17.385044;
            double longitude = 78.486671;

            // lets place some 10 random markers
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                // random latitude and logitude
                double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude,
                        longitude);

                // Adding a marker
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                        .title("Hello Maps " + i);

                Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", "
                        + randomLocation[1]);

                // changing marker color
                if (i == 0)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                if (i == 1)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                if (i == 2)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
                if (i == 3)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                if (i == 4)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
                if (i == 5)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
                if (i == 6)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                if (i == 7)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
                if (i == 8)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
                if (i == 9)
                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
                if (i == 9) {
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                    randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    /**
     * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }



    /*
     * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
     */
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }
}
```

Comment: Include activity_main Layout XML.

Comment: In your Log-cat shows class not found error.Your Google play library is not imported correctly.Check the project properties.

Comment: https://github.com/ErNaveen/google-play-services_lib  and https://github.com/ErNaveen/GoogleMapExample have a look this one

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you got an error in a fragment. In your error message it is stated: 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment.